# Fire jQuery event on tag generated by innerHTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using a javascript loop to create HTML code for a list, Example:

```
if (thisList.length > 0) {
    var myList = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < thisList.length; i++) {
        myList += '<li>Item ' + i + '</li>';
    }

    var myListBox = document.getElementById('my-list').innerHTML = myList;
}
```

I am then inserting the HTML code using:

```
<ul id="my-list" ></ul>
```

So the rendered HTML would be similar to:

```
<ul id="my-list" >
    <li>Item 0</li>
    <li>Item 1</li>
</ul>
```

My Problem: I cannot fire a jQuery event on the tags inside ul#my-list.  For example, the following jQuery code has no affect on the li tags.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('li').click(function() {
        $(this).hide();
});
```

How can I fire a jQuery event on those tags? Thanks in advance.

Comment: most probably a typo u did not close click function only document on ready is closed check console if this the code u have written and copied exactly here

Comment: Binding issue. You are trying to bind the click listener to html that has yet to be generated by your js.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is your bind function is happening before the element is rendered so jquery has nothing to bind to. You need a better way like checking when the li is clicked from my-list node.

If you look at

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('li') //this will have length 0 since the elements are not in the DOM tree yet.
});
```

You're looking for https://api.jquery.com/on/

```
$(function(){
    $('#my-list').on('click', 'li',function() {
        $(this).hide();
    });
});
```

the `$(function(){})` is short hand for `$(document).ready`

Answer (score 3):

This is because at *document.ready* time, your DOM is not completed - you are changing it in runtime. Modify your code in this way:

```
var myListBox = document.getElementById('my-list').innerHTML = myList;
$('li', myListBox ).click(function() {
    $(this).hide();
```

Now, after you created DOM, function onClick will bind.